# How to translate a statement from internal to external logic?

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

In the definition of [predicative topoi by van den Berg](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0959.pdf) we encounter the following definition of a collection square, for  an ambient category that is assumed to be locally cartesian closed, lextensive and regular:

> $$
>   \require{AMScd}
>   \begin{CD}
>     D        @>{q}>>  B       \\
>     @V{g}VV           @VV{f}V \\
>     C        @>>{p}>  A
>   \end{CD}
> $$
> A square as the one above will be called a collection square, if the following
> statement holds in the internal logic: for every $c \in C$ and cover $e : E \twoheadrightarrow$ $D_c$ there is a $c' \in C$
> with $p(c) = p(c')$ and a map $h : D_{c'} → D_{c}$ over $B$ which factors through $e$.

Given such an external square of four morphisms how can I state this statement externally?

This is my first foray into translating a statement in internal logic to external logic, so maybe there are simpler examples that could illustrate all the connectives and quantifiers within this statement.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, did you check reference [8] mentioned in the paper?

Comment: the statement seems to contain some dependent type theory (looking at the fiber over c :C), and it seems to quantify over types (the E). what does "cover" mean internally in that context?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg in [8] there is a similar definition 2.3 but in category of sets, I should probably edit that in the paper i am talking about, the ambient category is assumed to be lcc, lextensive and regular.

Comment: @Nico That's confusing me too as before that there is a definition 3.1 of a covering square, but as far as i can tell it uses external logic to define what it means.

Comment: I believe that Table 4.2 in [these notes of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.00948) might be useful. It spells out a fragment of the internal language in the special case of sheaf toposes over topological spaces. The case of arbitrary Grothendieck toposes is very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation is: for every morphism $c : T \to C$ and every
cover $e : E \twoheadrightarrow D_c$, there exist a cover $t : T' \twoheadrightarrow T$, a morphism $c' : T' \to C$, and a morphism $h : D_{c'} \to D_c$ factoring through $e : E \twoheadrightarrow D_c$, where $D_c$ and $D_{c'}$ are defined by the following pullback squares,
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D_c @>{d}>> D \\
@V{g_c}VV @VV{g}V \\
T @>>{c}> C
\end{CD}
\qquad
\begin{CD}
D_{c'} @>{d'}>> D \\
@V{g_{c'}}VV @VV{g}V \\
T' @>>{c'}> C
\end{CD}
$$
such that $p \circ c \circ t = p \circ c'$ and $q \circ d \circ h = q \circ d'$.

Frankly, this is not an appropriate first exercise in interpreting internal logic.
Even for experts it is a bit tricky.